# Many-to-junction entity in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Bit of an interesting one here I've not come across before. We've manually created a many-to-many relationship in EF6 using annotations:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class UserSchool
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

(Other additional properties omitted for brevity - suffice to say we have additional properties on the junction table, hence why we have created it explicitly)

So this works fine - we could use the fluent API to map the complex key, it's immaterial. Essentially we have joined the two standard tables via the junction into a many-to-many. Winner.

Now, we need to join the **junction** table (`UserSchool`) to another table, also as a many-to-many:

```
public class IPAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}

public class UserSchoolIPAddress
{
    ?? what to put in here

    public virtual UserSchool UserSchool { get; set; }

    public virtual IPAddress IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried both the fluent API mapping **AND** specifying the ID properties via naming convention and annotations: the fluent API mapping just fails, as I think it doesn't like using the navigational entities' properties; the ID binding with annotations just duplicates the `UserSchool` properties a second time on the table schema, causing us synchronicity problems.

So, has anyone come across this scenario before and found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it turns out I am an idiot. Looks like the framework WILL actually handle my scenario, but I had configured the property types incorrectly so there was a mismatch, hence EF tried to duplicate the new properties.

The completed definition of the many-to-junction table would therefore be as follows:

```
public class UserSchoolIPAddress
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserSchoolUserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int UserSchoolSchoolId { get; set; }   //<-- I had this set to a string for some reason, which broke everything

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public int IPAddress IPAddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserSchool UserSchool { get; set; }

    public virtual IPAddress IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```

So this will correctly create a second junction table using the FK to the "many" end (in this case `IPAddress`) and two FKs to the "junction" end (`UserSchool`), and combine all three FKs together into one complex PK on this "super-junction". Well done EF!

Answer (score 0):

You don't also need junction tables, EF creates it for you if you configure your entities in the right way.

In your case you have a user that can have many schools and a school that can have many users. If you create this model (and configure it via fluent apis) EF will create the table UserSchool for you and you don't need to manage it (EF will handle it for you).

About IPAddress if I understood your model, an IPAddress is used by a single user in a single school. Your model, with some navigation properties could be this.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<School> Schools {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<IpAddress> IpAddresses {get; set;}
}

public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<IpAddress> IpAddresses {get; set;}
}

public class IpAddress
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual User User {get; set;}
    public virtual School School {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question, we actually store additional data as properties of the junction mapping - for example, the `UserSchool` object actually has other foreign keys attached and permissions levels. So we need to configure them manually.